# Is it possible to run a VBScript in UNIX environment?

Tags: unix, vbscript, scripting, scheduling, execution

I've a Vbscript for merging excel sheet into a single workbook. I would like to know whether we could execute vbscript (.vbs) file in unix system. If yes, please help me with the procedures. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if you could, you wouldn't be able to run Excel.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure about Unices, but **on GNU/Linux** **it is possible to run VBScript using [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/)**, but **VBScript support is limited**.

On Debian/Ubuntu you can install as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine 
...
$
```

**To run** from command line:

```
$ wine cscript some-script.vbs
```

or

```
$ wine wscript some-script.vbs
```

For example I can run following script using Wine 1.7.19 from [Ubuntu Wine PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa):

```
' test.vbs

'WScript.Echo "Echo test"  ' doesn't work

'MsgBox "Message box!"     ' look like doesn't work either

' Write to file - works
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("out.txt", True)
objFile.Write "Output to file test" & vbCrLf
objFile.Close
```

run:

```
$ wine cscript test.vbs
fixme:vbscript:VBScript_SetScriptState unimplemented SCRIPTSTATE_INITIALIZED
fixme:scrrun:textstream_Close (0x13e208): stub
$ cat out.txt
Output to file test
$
```

Comment: looks like this works now `WScript.Echo "test"`

Answer (score 3):

You can install vbsedit on your windows box, use it to create and executable from the vbscript.  You can then use Wine/PlayonLinux to run the executable code.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question is Yes we can run VBScript on UNIX. But you will not be able to run excel on it. Although even if you get Excel to run using **WINE** I dont know how it would link the COM objects in the Excel to VBScript .

One possible altenative could be to install OpenOffice on the ***NIX** box and then configure OpenOffice to save and create Excel Docs(but I am not very sure about this)

Comment: The COM object is in Excel, not in VBScript, and I'd like to see how you run a VBScript in Unix.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers:- Just updated my answer! Got a typo and yes using WINE it could be used. Although I agree that it is not possible to run it on UNIX directly.(Do correct me if I am missing something)

Answer (score 1):

Use `wine start /path/to/your/script/script.vbs`.